# C# get the list of unmanaged C dll exports

Tags: c#, c, dll, interop, cdecl

I have a C dll with exported functions

I can use the command-line tool dumpbin.exe /EXPORTS to extract the list of exported functions, and then use them in my C# code to (successfully) call these functions.

Is there a way to get this exported-functions-list directly from .NET, without having to use an external command-line tool?

Thanks

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647766/exporting-dll-functions-to-unmanaged-programs

Comment: I need it the other way round, not DLLExport but DLLImport, which I use dynamically using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress win32api's.

Comment: The thing is I get DLLs from many sources, and the names of exported functions are not always only the original function names but include all other kinds of stuff like question marks and "@", so I need to get a list of all exported function-names to see which one contains the name I am looking for

Comment: This is not an option.  As a rule, you won't find unhelpful features built into VS.  Extracting the names of exported functions is just a small part of the job, you still need to know the types of the arguments and return value.

Comment: I know the method-signatures, I just don't know their names

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*As far as I know there is no class in the .Net Framework that
provides the information you need.*

However you can use the platform invocation services (PInvoke) of the .Net platform to
use the functions of the Win32 **dbghelp.dll** DLL. This DLL is part of
the *Debugging Tools for the Windows platform*. The dbghelp DLL provides
a function called `SymEnumerateSymbols64` which allows you to enumerate all
exported symbols of a dynamic link library. There is also a
newer function called `SymEnumSymbols` which also allows to enumerate
exported symbols.

The code below shows a simple example on how to use the `SymEnumerateSymbols64`
function.

```
[DllImport("dbghelp.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SymInitialize(IntPtr hProcess, string UserSearchPath, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool fInvadeProcess);

[DllImport("dbghelp.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SymCleanup(IntPtr hProcess);

[DllImport("dbghelp.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern ulong SymLoadModuleEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr hFile,
     string ImageName, string ModuleName, long BaseOfDll, int DllSize, IntPtr Data, int Flags);

[DllImport("dbghelp.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SymEnumerateSymbols64(IntPtr hProcess,
   ulong BaseOfDll, SymEnumerateSymbolsProc64 EnumSymbolsCallback, IntPtr UserContext);

public delegate bool SymEnumerateSymbolsProc64(string SymbolName,
      ulong SymbolAddress, uint SymbolSize, IntPtr UserContext);

public static bool EnumSyms(string name, ulong address, uint size, IntPtr context)
{
  Console.Out.WriteLine(name);
  return true;
}    

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  IntPtr hCurrentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;

  ulong baseOfDll;
  bool status;

  // Initialize sym.
  // Please read the remarks on MSDN for the hProcess
  // parameter.
  status = SymInitialize(hCurrentProcess, null, false);

  if (status == false)
  {
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Failed to initialize sym.");
    return;
  }

  // Load dll.
  baseOfDll = SymLoadModuleEx(hCurrentProcess,
                              IntPtr.Zero,
                              "c:\\windows\\system32\\user32.dll",
                              null,
                              0,
                              0,
                              IntPtr.Zero,
                              0);

  if (baseOfDll == 0)
  {
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Failed to load module.");
    SymCleanup(hCurrentProcess);
    return;
  }

  // Enumerate symbols. For every symbol the 
  // callback method EnumSyms is called.
  if (SymEnumerateSymbols64(hCurrentProcess,
      BaseOfDll, EnumSyms, IntPtr.Zero) == false)
  {
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Failed to enum symbols.");
  }

  // Cleanup.
  SymCleanup(hCurrentProcess);
}
```

In order to keep the example simple I did not use the
`SymEnumSymbols` function. I've also did the example
without using such classes as the `SafeHandle` class of
the .Net framework. If you need a example for the
`SymEnumSymbols` function, just let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elighting information, I have tested it and it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: One more thing, though, that is missing for me functionality-wise, is the ability to get the entry-point name for each of the function-names listed, this is because, for instance, the function named "GGT_RecommendMacros" has the entry point named "?GGT_RecommendMacros@@YAPADPBDPAHPAPAPAD@Z"

Comment: @ZivF: The ?GGT_RecommendMacros@@.." is the C++ name decoration. This is the entry point of your function. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085396/dumpbin-shows-strange-method-name-generating-exporting-function-in-ms-visual-c link for further explanation.